# Move Elasticbeanstalk Instance to Another Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

How do you migrate an AWS Elasticbeanstalk instance to another region?

Elasticbeanstalk ties a database to an instance. As far as I can tell, there is no way to change the database. I can create a new EB environment in the region, and I can copy the database as a snapshop, but I can't figure out how to connect the database to the instance.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

AWS Beanstalk stores configuration in S3 Buckets you can copy the content of S3 bucket to another region/Bucket and navigate to Beanstalk instance choose create new envrionment and then

Goto Beanstalk console -- > Applications --> Your application
--> ZenossAdminApp01 (This is my Beanstalk environment) --> Click on Actions --> Click on Saved Configurations.

Then Copy the S3Bucket content to another region and the do the below steps

[image]

Metabase is application name

Answer (score 0):

How are you connecting to the database presently from your EB ?. The deployed application in your EB should have the DB connection parameters. You can deploy the same application in your new region with update DB connection parameters pointing to the new DB.

Comment: That's my question: how do I update my Elasticbeanstalk DB connection? As far as I can tell, there is now way to change the DB in Configuration > Data Tier > RDS.

Comment: You can do it many ways. 1). using Elastic Beanstalk console 2). Use the connectivity information to connect to your DB from inside your application through environment variables. You can find more information here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html

Comment: The documentation you linked shows you how to create a new database, configure a database already connected to your instance, or connect a database through Django (NOT through EB). Django would know about the DB, but EB wouldn't, so things like scaling, creation, and updating would still happen to the old DB.